# Show text that depends on a number in a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, textbox, computation

I'm not sure what went wrong here:

```
Dim xapp As Integer = 20000
Dim xnet As Integer
Dim ans As String

xnet = NETPAYTextBox.Text
ans = AppstatusTextBox.Text

If (xapp < xnet) Then
    ans = "Approved"
Else
    ans = "Pending"
End If
```

It suppose to show "Approved" if the value of the NETPAYTextBox is greater than 20000 or show "Pending" if the value of the NETPAYTextBox is lower than 20000.

Comment: Where are you `trying to show the answer`?

Comment: Probably you want to SET the value of AppstatusTextBox.Text not reading from it

Comment: Doing this: `ans = AppstatusTextBox.Text` _**will not**_ automatically change the text in the TextBox just because you modify the `ans` variable, if you thought so.

Comment: use :  `AppstatusTextBox.Text = "Approved"`

Comment: @zaggler I was trying to show either "Approved" or "Pending" it depends if NETPAYTextBox contains integer that's greater or lower than 20000.

Comment: The question is WHERE do you want to show the answer?

Comment: The answer will show on AppstatusTextBox.Text. "Approved" or "Pending".

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR it worked!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @DorineMae you had `ans = AppstatusTextBox.Text` around the wrong way

Comment: @DorineMae you can't assume a user will enter a valid number, please see me answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick. It makes sure you have an `Integer` and if so do the comparison and set the text depending on the outcome...

```
    Dim xnet As Integer = 0

    AppstatusTextBox.Text = CStr(If(Integer.TryParse(NETPAYTextBox.Text, xnet) AndAlso 20000 < xnet, "Approved", "Pending"))
```

Comment: For some reason I've never thought of using a TryParse method with a short circuiting operator. Seems so obvious now that I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have your code like this

```
Dim xapp As Integer = 20000
Dim xnet As Integer
Dim ans As String


If (xapp < xnet) Then
    ans = "Approved"
Else
    ans = "Pending"
End If

NETPAYTextBox.Text = xnet.toString
AppstatusTextBox.Text = ans
```

You want to set a value to `ans` Before u display it.

Doing this

```
xnet = NETPAYTextBox.Text
```

You set `xnet`to equal the text `NETPAYTextBox`

But by doing

```
NETPAYTextBox.text = xnet.to string
```

You setting the text of the text box to equal `xnet.`

Answer (score -5):

Don't you have to convert the text to a integer, you are comparing a interger with a string now....

Make NETPAYTextBox a numericupdown

Comment: No he/she isn't. When setting the `xnet` variable the string is implicitly (correct me if I'm using the wrong term here) converted to an Integer.

Comment: Yes it is invalid, basic vb.net 2015 setting and you get; Additional information: Conversion from string "sadfasd" to type 'Integer' is not valid. But hey, if you all know it better, search it out ;)

Comment: That's because it contains letters! If you just type in numbers than don't exceed 2147483647 you will not have a problem (as long as Option Strict is off). Try it.

Comment: and that why you have to use a nummericupdown, so you force people to enter a numeric value. duuhhhh

Comment: I know that, I didn't say you shouldn't/wouldn't :). I just responded to `you are comparing a interger with a string now` - because that statement is incorrect.

Comment: My statement is 100% correct, if someone enters a text in the box, you are comparing a string with a integer, so you can cast the text to a integer, or, which is a better solution to begin with, prevent them from entering text... But hey, I have a live, I have wasted enough time on this, I'm off....

Comment: Nonono. If someone enters normal text you'll get an exception (like you wrote in your previous comment) which means that you are not comparing anything. Otherwise the string is converted to an integer and you'll be comparing two integers. A string cannot be compared to an Integer unless the string is converted to an integer.